# How to remove an element in an object array by the content of a field? (map returning undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a `todo list` in React.
I have a state that stores `id` and `content` of each task:

```js
this.state = {tasks: [{id: 123, content: 'Walk with dog'}, {id: 2, content: 'Do groceries'}]}
```

I managed to add elements by using

```js
this.setState([...this.state.tasks, newTask])
```

However, I'm struggling to remove elements. I thought about using a map:

```js
this.state.tasks.map((task)=>{
   if(task.id != 123){return task}
})
```

However, it's appending `undifened` elements when the id is found, instead of nothing.

[image: map returning undefined]

What should I do?

Comment: PS: I know class components are outdated over functional components with hooks, but i'm trying to create a background in react basics before diving into more advanced stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter method to filter items in your array:

```js
let filtered = tasks.filter(task => task.id != 123)
```

Comment: You can also just have tasks be an object rather than an array, with the key for each task being the id and the value being the content.

Comment: Thank you @Aamir! I came up with that model but I wasn't sure it was good or not. I'll try to refactor the code using your suggestion